# Custom TableView section headers with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have table view section headers which display summary information (a total of a particular property) about the objects contained in that section.

When a user deletes an object by swiping on the table cell, I delete the object from the model and FetchedResultsController removes that cell from the table view through its delegate.

Deleting an object:

```
    NSManagedObject *mo = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self.context performBlockAndWait:^{
        [self.context deleteObject:mo];
        [[APDatabase database] saveContext];
    }];
```

And in response, FRC calls its delegate and I animate the cell being removed.

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{ ...

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
... }
```

The problem is that the totals in the section header will now have changed but the section header still displays the old total. I can't call `[tableView reloadData]` because that would stop the animation of the cell being deleted.

How can I update the section header totals when an object is deleted?

The section headers are created using

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

and working through the objects contained in the section using `[theSection objects]`

Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `headerViewForSection:` on the table view for the appropriate section to get the view that you previously returned, then update its contents directly.

This is a similar approach to updating cell contents directly rather than asking the table view to reload when the change is just related to an item being updated (rather than added or removed).

Comment: I did think of doing this but how to know if the section index still corresponds to the section I want to update? Does this function get called before the FRC calls the section update delegate method?

Comment: The FRC tells you the section, if you want to update a different section from the one where the item is removed then you need to keep track of the sections yourself so you can find the correct one...

Comment: What I mean is, say your delegate method is called by FRC and it says that section 2 item 1 is deleted. How do I know whether section 2 in the FRC's dataset corresponds to the section the item was deleted from or if that section no longer exists since it only had one item in it and section 2 in FRC's dataset is now the old Section 3 since the dataset changes before the delegate is called.

Comment: I think the best way to do it is to just run through all the section header views in controllerDidChangeContent which gets called after the two separate methods for objects and sections. That way I'm not dealing with a dataset and a table view that doesn't match.